# Swift iOS -Can a Loop Run Faster then Date Secs generated by Date().timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: ios, swift, function, loops, nsdate

I pull some data from Firebase, add the data to a loop, then print the secs as each loop is ran. Is there a chance that the loop will run so fast that it will print the same secs twice?

For e.g. in the code below is this outcome possible?

```
image0__1507792099
image1__1507793000
image2__1507793001
image3__1507793001
image4__1507793002
image5__1507793002
```

Can both image2 and image3 get printed with the same time stamp and can the same thing happen with image4 and image5?

```
var images:[String] = []
let secs = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

myRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { 
     (snapshot) in

     if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{

          let image0 = dict["image0"] as? String
          let image1 = dict["image1"] as? String
          let image2 = dict["image2"] as? String
          let image3 = dict["image3"] as? String
          let image4 = dict["image4"] as? String
          let image5 = dict["image5"] as? String

          self.images.append(image0)
          self.images.append(image1)
          self.images.append(image2)
          self.images.append(image3)
          self.images.append(image4)
          self.images.append(image5)

         for image in self.images{
             print("\(image)__\(self.secs)")
             let x = someConversionMethodThatReturnsAnImage(str: image)
             saveData(image: x)
         }
     }
}

fileprivate func saveData(image: UIImage){
        let imageExt = String(describing: secs).appending(".jpg")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        let imagePath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(imageExt)?.path
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath!, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    }
```

FYI the reason I'm asking this question is because I'm using the `secs` as an extension to add the Firebase data to the DocumentsDirectory. Everything has been working fine but I'm not sure if there can be an overlap in time which means some of the data that is pulled and saved will be overwritten if they both have the same time stamp. I was pondering using arc4Random instead.

Comment: Why not just use a [`UUID`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) instead of a timestamp or `arc4Random`: `let uuid = UUID().uuidString`

Comment: @ColGraff thanks for the reply! Notice at the bottom of the post I put was thinking about arc4Random. I know I can use uuid too. I really want to know is this scenario possible?

Comment: I wouldn't use time to uniquely identify any data in a loop unless I was certain that the loop was orders of magnitude slower than the granularity of my timestamp. It's just not worth it down the line if it does happen. A `UUID` is much safer and at least as easy to use. It's also designed exactly for this use-case as opposed to a simple random number through `arc4Random`

Comment: @ColGraff hey man/woman thanks, you answered the question. In but so many words you're saying the duplicate time stamps are possible. That's exactly what I needed to know. Would you mind making it an official answer so I can accept it as the official answer? I'm sure this situation has crossed other devs minds.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because your question is about the speed of the loop, something I didn't answer. If you change the question to be about how to best make a unique filename then my comment would be an answer.

Comment: @ColGraff ok, gimme like 1 hr. I'm away from my cpu. When I get back to it I'll change it then message you.

Comment: "Can a Loop Run Faster then Date Secs generated by Date().timeIntervalSince1970". Yes, especially if you round to integers, like your above code. But other have suggested, it's not prudent to use timestamp as unique identifier, regardless. Use `UUID` or some synchronized incremented value.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the help

Comment: @ColGraff you know actually I thought this over. I want to leave the question the way it is only because I want others who don't know but need to know that a loop can run faster then the date in secs. You was right when you said you answered which is a better alternative however you indirectly answered the question. Even if you put something short with a 1 sentence answer I'll choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you certainly can use a timestamp to make filenames unique I wouldn't do it. Even if it works right now circumstances may change down the line, making the loop run faster and causing you to lose data because you create two files during the same quanta. There's also factors such as clocks changing due to daylight savings or other adjustments. I would avoid that chance completely by using a method that is much safer: using a UUID.

A UUID is a series of values that are designed to be as unique as possible, either through an algorithm or through random means. They are much safer than a timestamp or a value generated through `arc4Random` and they have the additional benefit of being self-documenting in your code. When you see the [`UUID struct`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) you know at a glance that you are creating a unique identifier.

Apple's `UUID` uses [RFC 4122 version 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.4) which has [5.3x10^36 possible values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), leaving the chances of [collisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions) to be infinitesimal.

You can replace this line:

```
    let imageExt = String(describing: secs).appending(".jpg")
```

with this:

```
    let imageExt = UUID().uuidString.appending(".jpg")
```